# SQL Function Error: 1064

Tags: sql

I have a problem with creating my own function in SQL. I get an error #1064 - wrong syntax on line 10 (a line with 'create function') and I can't figure out what am I doing wrong?

```
create table students (
id int primary key,
name varchar(30),
surname varchar(30),
class char(4),
born datetime,
grade varchar(10)
)

create function returnGrade
(@class char(4))
return varchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
declare @return varcahr(10)
@class = SUBSTRING(@class, 2, 1)
  SELECT @return = CASE @class
  WHEN '1' then 'first'
  WHEN '2' then 'second'
  WHEN '3' then 'third'
  WHEN '4' then 'fourth'
  ELSE 'unknown'
  END
return @return
END
```

PS variable class looks like this: 'T3.A', 'T4.A', 'T4.B' etc.

Comment: Try adding a `GO` between the create table and the create function. Also, the `declare @return varcahr(10)` should be `varchar(10)`

Comment: well.. I added GO and it wrote me "You have an 1064 err on line #9 near 'go
create function returnGrade..."

Answer (score 0):

Your code:
`declare @return varcahr(10)`

Both a typo and using a reserved word.

`declare @ret varchar(10)`

Answer (score 0):

Please try as follow, in your statement returns (s) is missing.

```
create function returnGrade
(
    @class char(4)
)
returns varchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @return varchar(10)
    set @class = SUBSTRING(@class, 2, 1)
      SELECT @return = CASE @class
      WHEN '1' then 'first'
      WHEN '2' then 'second'
      WHEN '3' then 'third'
      WHEN '4' then 'fourth'
      ELSE 'unknown'
    END

    return @return
END
```

Comment: it's the same. SQL can't go through 'create function returnGrade' line :-/

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not mentioned which DB i am assuming it as SQL Server.

You have several typos in your code.

Here is the correction

```
create function returnGrade
(@class char(4))
returns varchar(10) -- returns not return
AS
BEGIN
declare @return varchar(10)   -- varchar not varcahr
set @class = SUBSTRING(@class, 2, 1)  -- set was missing
  SELECT @return = CASE @class
  WHEN '1' then 'first'
  WHEN '2' then 'second'
  WHEN '3' then 'third'
  WHEN '4' then 'fourth'
  ELSE 'unknown'
  END
return @return
END
```

The above code compiles fine and returns value too.

```
select dbo.returngrade('A2')
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me.

```
CREATE TABLE students
    (
      id INT PRIMARY KEY ,
      name VARCHAR(30) ,
      surname VARCHAR(30) ,
      class CHAR(4) ,
      born DATETIME ,
      grade VARCHAR(10)
    )

GO -- Added GO


CREATE FUNCTION returnGrade ( @class CHAR(4) )
RETURNS VARCHAR(10) -- Changed to RETURNS from RETURN
AS 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @return VARCHAR(10) -- Corrected the typo varcahr
        SET @class = SUBSTRING(@class, 2, 1) -- Added SET
        SELECT  @return = CASE @class
                            WHEN '1' THEN 'first'
                            WHEN '2' THEN 'second'
                            WHEN '3' THEN 'third'
                            WHEN '4' THEN 'fourth'
                            ELSE 'unknown'
                          END
        RETURN @return
    END

GO
```

Comment: This wrote "err on line 11 near 'GO..." :-/